# Series expansion of the power Reciprocal gamma function

Tags: taylor-expansion, special-functions, gamma-function

Based on the post [Non-recursive closed-form of the coefficients of Taylor series of the reciprocal gamma function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978944/non-recursive-closed-form-of-the-coefficients-of-taylor-series-of-the-reciprocal), is it possible to obtain some Taylor expansion series for
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{[\Gamma(z)]^n},
$$
around zero? Here $n$ is some positive integer and $z>0$.

Comment: The series coefficients, either by $n$th derivative or integral transform, for $f(x)^r$ where $f(x)$ is non-elementary usually have very complicated formulas

Answer (score 1):

$$f_n(z)=\frac{1}{\big(\Gamma (z)\big)^n}=\frac{z^n}{\big(z\,\Gamma (z)\big)^n}$$
By Taylor
$$\frac{1}{z\,\Gamma (z)}=1+\sum_{k=1}^p a_k\, z^k + O(z^{p+1})$$ where the $a_k$'s are known.

$$f_n(z)=z^n \Bigg(1+\sum_{k=1}^p a_k\, z^k + O(z^{p+1}) \Bigg)^n=z^n\Bigg(1+n\sum_{k=1}^p \frac{b_k}{k!}\, z^k \Bigg)+ O(z^{p+1})$$

Now, using the binomial expansion,we have the $b_k$'s
$$b_1=a_1$$
$$b_2= (n-1)a_1^2+2a_2$$
$$b_3=(n-1)(n-2)a_1^3+6(n-1)a_1a_2+6a_3$$
The next one is too long to type here but this is the idea.

Comment: @StevenClark. Sorry for the typo ! Fixed now