# Multinomial theorem for a power series

Tags: power-series, binomial-theorem, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

I was wondering if there is a version of the multinomial theorem for the expression:
$$
(1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^k)^n.
$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expand the binomial and you're left with powers of the power series. The multinomial theorem works here too, e.g.$$\left(\sum_{i\ge0} a_i x^i\right)^2 = \sum_{i\ge0} {a_i}^2 x^{2i} + 2 \sum_{1\le i<j<\infty} a_i a_j x^{i+j}$$

Comment: hello, is there a general expression for the product of $n$ power series? I trying to obtain a general expression for it. thanks

Comment: That's where the multinomial theorem kicks in, but writing out the expansion like I've done for the $n=2$ case can be very lengthy for $n\ge3$. The $n=3$ case is$$\left(\sum_{i\ge0}a_ix^i\right)^3 = \sum_{i\ge0} {a_i}^3 x^{3i} + 3 \sum_{1\le i<j<\infty} \left({a_i}^2 a_j x^{2i+j} + a_i {a_j}^2 x^{i+2j}\right) + 6 \sum_{1\le i<j<k<\infty} a_i a_j a_k x^{i+j+k}$$Note that $1,3,6$ are multinomial coefficients (think of the coefficients in the expansion of $(a+b+c)^3$), and the powers of $x$ in each sum are expressed as integer partitions of $n$.

Comment: The answer to the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4750740/series-expansion-of-the-power-reciprocal-gamma-function/4752004#4752004 may help for trying to find a general formula.